# Removing ChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase `childEventListener` which is added N-number of times to a `Node` to get data from the DB.

Now I'm trying to remove the `childEventListener` and it does not seem to work and I get duplicate data.

```
    query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("chat")
            .child("room-messages")
            .child(roomID)
            .orderByChild("timestamp")
            .limitToLast(index);

    paginationListener = query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.getKey() + " - Single Value");
            try {
                Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
                message.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new GetPaginatedMessage(message));
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Type Cast Exception Caught");
            }

        }
```

and removing the listener like

```
 if (query != null && paginationListener != null) {
        query.removeEventListener(paginationListener);
    }
```

It doesn't seem to work and I get duplicate data.
Any help is appriciated

Comment: Calling `removeEventListener()` removes the listener from that location. It will stop firing events after it has completed them for data it's already received. If you're still getting calls to the listener, something else is going on that is unfortunately impossible to say from the code you shared.

Comment: Hmm, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qBPLgP35QPs closely relates what I'm doing here! Any idea for an alternative? I can share more code as well

Comment: In that firebase-talk thread Jonny talks about the same thing I mention in "after it has completed them for data it's already received". If you don't want to process any more data, just set a boolean flag when you remove the listener and check that value in your `onChildAdded` before processing.

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `removeEventListener()` removes the listener from that location. It will not fire events for any data received after you call it.  It may still fire some events for data it's already received.

[Jonny's answer on the firebase-talk group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qBPLgP35QPs) about this same behavior:

> events are queued up asynchronously and potentially run on a different thread, so there might have been events queued up before you call removeEventListener.