# Android studio FirebaseDatabase : RemoveEventListener not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem in my app. I am calling valueEventListener and I want when user close the activity or start another activity stop listening so I call removeEventListener but it is not working

```
//Firebase
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mUser;


//Firebase
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    user_id = mUser.getUid();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    listener =mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            url = dataSnapshot.child(CHILD_PIC).child(pic).getValue().toString();
            player = dataSnapshot.child(CHILD_PLAYERS).child(players).getValue().toString();
            Img_check = dataSnapshot.child(CHILD_PIC).child(CHILD_CHECK).getValue().toString();
            balls = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(user_id).child("Balls").getValue().toString();
            number_miss = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(user_id).child("Mission").getValue().toString();
            Isso = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(user_id).child("Isso").getValue().toString();
            Tx = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(user_id).child("Tx").getValue().toString();
            Three = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(user_id).child("Three").getValue().toString();
            //verify = dataSnapshot.child(check).child(user_id).child(CHILD_CHECK).getValue().toString();
           // Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, verify, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            dialog_mi(number_miss);setimg(url);checkverify(verify,player,Img_check);putfloat(Isso,Tx,Three);
            //miss(number_miss);
            //getballs(balls);
            //checkplayer(player);
            //checkvefify(verify,player);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(PlayActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    mDatabase.removeEventListener(listener);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MissionActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("level", mission);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? What is the behavior you see? What did you expect? Keep in mind that Firebase will keep firing for all data it already retrieved. So if you remove the listener after the first `onChildAdded()`, it will still be called for all the other initial data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140289/removing-childeventlistener/46158477#46158477

Comment: Where are you calling removeeventlistener.  Don't see it in the code example above?

Comment: check updates,please

Comment: please help me guys